Strong notion of neighbors expanding
In the context of graphs, a $\Delta$-regular bipartite graph $G =(L, R, E)$ is called $(\beta, \varepsilon)$-left-expander if for any subset $S$ of $L$ at the size at most $|S| <\beta |L|$ the size of the neighbors set to $L$ is at least $(1-\varepsilon)\Delta$. A unique neighbor to $S$ is a vertex in $R$ that is connected to exactly one vertex in $S$.
It can be shown that the number of unique neighbors to $S$ is at least $(1-2\varepsilon)\Delta|S|$, and therefore the number of neighbors to $S$ that are connected to at least two vertices in $S$ is at most $2\varepsilon\Delta|S|$.
I wonder about the existence of graphs satisfies the following: suppose $S \subset L$ is at size at most $\beta |L|$, and denote by $N_{i}(S)$ the set of neighbors to $S$ such any of them is connected to exactly $i$ vertices in $L$. Then $|N_{i}(S)| < \varepsilon^{i} \Delta |S|$.
Do we have such graphs? Or is it even likely to hope of having such graphs?
